# Is it possible to set popover postion with right and top property?

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, css, popover

I am using Bootstrap popover in gantt chart. I am setting position of popover dynamically based on mouse hover position.

```
popover.css('left', event.pageX + 'px');
popover.css('top', event.pageY+ 'px')
```

On the right extremes the popover disappers (I have removed the text wrap and scroll for page). I thought setting the `right` instead of `left` would fix this problem on the right edges alone.

```
popover.css('right', event.pageX + 'px');
popover.css('top', event.pageY+ 'px');
```

But this is not working. Can anyone help with it. If my idea is wrong, is there any better way to do that?

Comment: Hi Jenny, You will need to provide more information - not working is very vague.  What exactly isn't working?

Comment: Sorry about the vague info. When I set 'right ' to the event.pageX I get the popove positioned in the left extreme.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When setting position of `left` just make sure you do not exceed page limits.

```
popover.css({
    left: event.pageX + popover.outerWidth() + 10 < $(window).width()
          ? event.pageX
          : $(window).width() - popover.outerWidth() - 10
});
```